# Visual Basic 2010 no release option?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lechw.png

I've got expert settings enabled, but I can't change the build mode.  I don't have an option in the project properties either to change the build mode.  I need to change to release.

Comment: Build -> Configuration Manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that Visual Basic projects always defaults to Release (assuming they are the first project created in the solution), and so the VB profile settings don't show the configuration manager dropdown.  However, you might be able to view the settings by:

- Adding the Solution Configurations dropdown to the toolbar if it's not shown by default.  You can do this by expanding the Add or Remove buttons.
- Adding it manually by going to Tools -> Customize.  From there:

  1. Switch to the Commands tab
  2. Select Toolbar = Standard
  3. Click Add Command.
  4. Select the "Build" category.
  5. Find the Solution Configurations dropdown towards the bottom, and add it.

(disclaimer: I don't have VS2010 handy, but these steps should work the same)